# Incrementing timer in method not working - but works without using a method

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, methods

I've came across a problem that just baffles me, and that I can't explain whatsoever.
Here it is:

```
public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float _myTimer = 0;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        StartTimer(_myTimer);

        //_myTimer += Time.deltaTime;
    }

    private void StartTimer(float timer)
    {
        timer += Time.deltaTime;
    }
}
```

I expect the timer to increment here... But it does not increment.
However, the timer increments as soon as I ditch the StartTimer() method and just increment it like in the comment. Why is this?

Thanks in advance!
Thrindil

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are passing the parameter by value. Any changes made are discarded as the method operates on a copy.

If you change it to a ref parameter, your code will work as expected.

```
public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float _myTimer = 0;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        StartTimer(ref _myTimer);

        //_myTimer += Time.deltaTime;
    }

    private void StartTimer(ref float timer)
    {
        timer += Time.deltaTime;
    }
}
```

As noted in the comment below, you don't need an explicit parameter since it is a member of the same type the methods are members of.

Comment: Given that _myTimer is a private member you don't even need it as a parameter, this._myTimer += Time.deltaTime in StartTimer() would do the trick

Comment: @HasaniH You're totally right, but this was just to sketch the problem here.
As for the solution: Wow. Can't believe I've been programming for this long without knowing this. Are parameters always passed by value if you don't use the ref keyword?

Comment: Depends on the context, in a manner of speaking. A ref type variable is passed by value, that's the reference itself. But you can modify any fields and they'll be visible to the caller. But if you assign a new object to that parameter, that won't have any effect up the call stack. Value types must always be passed as ref if callee wants to make any changes as they are passed as a copy.

Comment: There are some corner cases to the above comment, but general guideline holds.